# Is there any formal way of tagging an author in git commit?

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket-server

We are using **Jira** and **Stash** for collaboration.

My question is I want to **mention**(tag) another developer(author) in my commit message. I can just write the author's git username but I am asking if there is any formal way of doing it.

For example you can mention **Jira** case by specifying its **issue-key** ( say appName-123), then stash will automatically linkify the issue-key ([appName-123](http://caseurlinjira)) to the case url in **Jira**.

*Is there anything similar to this for tagging an author?*

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't support multiple authors, it's a kind of bug. but u can give credit to your partner by editing configuration for that period of time to   `git config user.name "Author 1 and Author 2"`  or You can use hitch to pair authors please refers to these links [pairing with hitch](http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2009/04/20/pairing-with-hitch.html) , [hitch configuration](http://thechangelog.com/hitch-git-author-attribution-helper-for-pair-programmers/)

Comment: Thanks, lets see there are any other options. Otherwise I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stash itself doesn't attempt to do anything special for git commit message content when it comes to usernames. It seems there is not an existing [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3609?jql=project%20%3D%20STASH%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20%22commit%20mention%22) for it currently.